# What is the legal definition of "week" in the context of an independent work agreement?

Tags: contract-law, israel

I have an independent work agreement with a client and there is some ambiguity with the definition of the word "week" which is being used to describe a fixed quota that should be achieved per week.

There is no explicit definition of "week" in the agreement, so I want to know what a "week" implicitly implies, is it equal to a time period of 7 days? Or is it a work week with only 5 days? My client thinks it is the latter but I think it is the former.

Also, does a week cover a partial calendar week which can occur at the start and end of a month? How many days is a "week" in that case?

P.S The jurisdiction is Israel but I would not mind getting a general answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If your contract does not define “week” it takes its normal meaning

The normal meaning of [week](https://thelawdictionary.org/week/) is a period of 7 consecutive days. Depending on context this may be ‘free-floating’ or start on a particular day; usually Sunday in English speaking countries YMMD.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it makes sense.